# Mongo DB find query with Regex not returning expected output

Tags: java, database, mongodb

Below is my query which return result from database. I am using 3.2.22 mongo version

```
db.courses.find({_id:"edX-NYIF+CR.5x"});
```

Now I want fetch record of course Id which will be in lower case so I used below query  it seems working fine if i use alpha character but not getting result for following course Id.

```
db.getCollection('courses').find({"_Id": { $regex : "edX-NYIF+CR.5x$" , $options: 'i'}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex expression string needs to be escaped

```
db.getCollection('courses').find({"courseId": { $regex : "edX\\-NYIF\\+CR\\.5x$" , $options: 'i'}})
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j-e0mQ5o6wW)

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, your query looks OK... but I don't think this is going to work as you expected, because of the format of your ID.

The string `"edX-NYIF+CR.5x"` contains characters that have specific meanings for regexes, such as `.` and `+`, and perhaps some other IDs contain others. You should escape these first.

[Looking at another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex), there's a simple way to escape regex-sensitive characters:

```
string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&')
```

So escape your ID string and then use it in your query.

[Here's a handy reference for special characters inside regular expressions, should you need it.](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharacters.html)

Comment: could you help me with query .?

Comment: Wait: are you querying for the `_id` field or the `courseId` field? Your queries do not use the same field for querying. Was that a mistake in your question?